# How to specify "windows-curses" be installed only on Windows with pypi

Tags: python, pip, pypi

This is my setup.py:

```
 install_requires=[
        'requests',
        'appdirs',
        'windows-curses; platform_system=="Windows"'
        ],
```

When I install the project on Windows it says `'windows-curses; platform_system=="Windows"'` can not be found, however `pip install windows-curses` works.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement windows-curses; platform_system == "Windows" (from nodreader==0.1.9) (from versions: none)
```

Comment: What version of `setuptools` are you using? It seems to be interpreting the package name as including the platform specifier. Can you try putting a space before the semicolon?